# Call Method.invoke() when arguments in array

Tags: java, reflection, variadic-functions

I have the following interface:

```
interface Foo {
  void bar(String a, int b);
}
```

I want to invoke `Foo.bar` (on an implementation of Foo) reflectively. *However, the arguments are in array* and i do not know the size of it.

The following does not work:

```
void gee(Foo someFoo, Method bar, Object[] args) {
  bar.invoke(someFoo, args);
}
```

That does not work because `args` is threated by the compiler as a single argument and the array is not "expanded" to vararg but is wrapped (internally) in one more array with single element, i.e.

```
@Test
public void varArgTest() {
  assertTrue(varArgFoo(new Object[] {1, 2}) == 1);
}

private static <T> int varArgFoo(T... arg) {
    return arg.length;
}
```

How can i call `Method.invoke()` in this case so that the array is threated as vararg?
Or more general question: how do i call vararg method when arguments are in array i do not knew the size of the array until runtime.

Comment: Your question cannot be deleted anymore, too many SO users have posted answers and otherwise spent attention on it.  You can flag a moderator but you'll need to come up with a *really* good reason to get them to delete it for you.  I'd recommend some kind of national security emergency.

Comment: @Hans Passant I did flag it, but no moderator responded. I changed the title to do not appear in the searches, since the question is misleading ... even the most voted answer is wrong and misleading

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The following does not work:

Yes it does.

> That does not work because args is threated by the compiler as a
>   single argument and the array is not "expanded" to vararg but is
>   wrapped (internally) in one more array with single element, i.e.

With the code you have presented, the array's elements should become the varargs arguments. If that's not happening for you, either you are not showing your actual code, or something else is wrong.

If somehow your `args` variable does not have an array type (e.g. it is typed `Object`), then that could happen. But that is not the code you're showing.

Or if you have some "additional" arguments you are not showing (e.g. you are trying to do something like `bar.invoke(someFoo, firstArg, args);`, then it will not expand `args`, because you are using the method in the varargs form already.

Comment: You are right, in my test case, by mistake i had `assertFalse` instead `assertTrue`. But i can not delete the question. I flagged it so that moderator would delete it, but did not happen yet.

Answer (score 10):

A vararg parameter is actually an array parameter with a bit of extra metadata. So when you use `Method.invoke`, you need to wrap the array in *another* array:

```
Object[] varargs = new Object[] { 10, 20 };
Object argumentArray = new Object[] { varargs };
method.invoke(target, argumentArray);
```

Comment: From the question, the OP sounds like they have the opposite problem, i.e. they want it not wrapped but it is wrapped

Comment: @newacct: It's far from clear - but the way I've described it is the only way I can understand things going wrong...